# Given action "LoadEntries", reducer "entries" returned undefined.

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, reducers

When I run my app, I get following errors.

> Error: Given action "LoadEntries", reducer "entries" returned
>   undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the
>   previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can
>   return null instead of undefined.

Following is the action file.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const loadEntries = () => {

     return dispatch => {

        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
             .then(res => {
                dispatch({type: 'LoadEntries', payload: res.data});
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error("Error: " + error);
             })    
    }
}
```

Following is the reducer.

```
export default (state = [], action) => {

    console.log("Action: " + JSON.stringify(action) + " State: " + state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LoadEntries':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

When I run the app I get the following log in console for reducer.

> Action: {"type":"LoadEntries"} State:

Following is the Index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import reducer from './store/reducer';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,

    document.getElementById('root'));
```

Also attached a screenshot of console.

[image: console screenshot]

Thanks.

Comment: i dont find any issues in your code. can you share the code where actions has been called

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the action on both the resolve or reject of promise inside the action dispatcher.

Your dispatcher should always return an action.

I would also recommend to handle the rejection in a separate action.